# How to subclass np.ndarray so that inherited methods do not return instances of '__main__.ClassName'

Tags: numpy, inheritance, subclass, numpy-ndarray, new-operator

How can I retain the functionality of methods of np.ndarray when subclassing it? I have been following the instructions [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html) on subclassing `np.ndarray`.

In their simple example they construct:

```
class InfoArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(subtype, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
                strides=None, order=None, info=None):
        obj = super().__new__(subtype, shape, dtype,
                              buffer, offset, strides, order)
        obj.info = info
        return obj


    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
```

But now the methods assiciated with `np.ndarray` return instances of `InfoArray`:

```
a = InfoArray(shape=(5,), info="some information")

a.mean()
>>> InfoArray(0.5)

type(a.mean())
>>> __main__.InfoArray
```

whereas with a classic `np.array`i a float is returned

```
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b.mean()
>>> 2.0

type(b.mean())
>>> np.float64
```

How can I prevent this and keep the original functionality of the methods associated with `np.ndarray`?

I realise I could redefine the methods like so:

```
class InfoArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(subtype, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
                strides=None, order=None, info=None):
        obj = super().__new__(subtype, shape, dtype,
                              buffer, offset, strides, order)
        obj.info = info
        return obj


    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def mean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.float64(super().mean(*args, **kwargs))

c = InfoArray(shape=(5,), info="some information")

c.mean()
>>> 0.5

type(c.mean())
>>> np.float64
```

but would rather avoid doing this for all methods.

Comment: look at what `matrix` and `maskedArray` do.

Comment: It may be enough to check if `if isinstance(obj, ndarray):`, in `finalize`.